# How To Increase Swap Size & Create Additional Paritions within Drive with 4 Primary Partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, swap

This is what my Gparted view of drive looks like:

[image]

To further elaborate, I have four primary partitions in this 525Gb (or so) SSD drive in my laptop. They are:

- SDA1 - System Reserve
- SDA2 - Windows 10 (NTFS)
- SDA3 - Data (NTFS)
- SDA4 - Extended - (not clear on this but its a sum of SDA5 & SDA6)
- SDA6 - Ubuntu partition (EXT4)
- SDA5 - linux swap (only 2gb currently, needs to be increased)

As recommended in other answers, I tried using Gparted to resize swap, however, i get the error that I cannot create more than 4 primary partitions. How can I resolve this and then increase swap and also utilise the remaining space on the drive?

Comment: Resize the extended partition `sda4` first, then you can resize partitions which are located in the extended partition or create additional logical partitions. You will have to run gparted from live-USB.

Comment: @mook765 Sorry, Im not clear on that comment. It appears that SDA4 is the sum of SDA6 & SDA5, if that makes sense. I donot want to touch SDA6 because its my main partition / drive I use daily (Ubuntu partition)

Comment: `sda4` is the extended partition, it is a container for logical partitions. The sum of all logical partitions can't be bigger then the container holding them. Just make the container (the extended partition `sda4`) as big as possible, should take the rest of the whole drive, then you have more space in the container and you can rearrange it's contents or add more logical partitions in it. You don't need to touch `sda6`. http://www.linfo.org/extended_partition.html

Comment: This can be done... but your sda3 partition is also full. Do you wish to increase the size of sda3 at the same time? Your sda6 is also full. Resize also? How much RAM do you have? I can outline the steps based on your answers.

Comment: thanks guys, I think I can follow from here.  mook765 has kindly elaborated so it makes sense now.